# Calculation from specific value php array

Tags: php

Hello all i need help and want to get idea about my case

**my case example :** some name asigned powers like

- jhon = 20
- aliza= 30
- rehana=40
- adiba=50
- black = 1000
- white = 7500
- red =  3500

when someone enter in input amount 50 then

- i need output ( jhon and aliza )

if input amount is  70 then

- output like this ( adiba and jhon )

if  input is 4500 then

- how get output like this **Black and Red**

```
   $groups_name = array("jhon"=>"20", "aliza"=>"30", "rehana"=>"40",
       "adiba"=>"50", "black"=>"1000", "white"=>"7500", "red"=>"3500");
```

Comment: Two questions to understand your query in a better way,
Q1. What do you expect in result when someone enters values which isn't an addition of any values you've got in the array (ex. 100 or 210),
Q2. What if someone enters a value which is a sum of three elements up there (jhon 20 + rehana 40 + black 1000) = 1060

Comment: yes if some one enter value 1060 ouput need  jhon  + rehana  + black  if value is eqval 5 names then output 5 names if value not match in array then msg show (name not fount)

Comment: Lookup coin change problem.Also, SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: brother i need help about my case  i dont understand what you your mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with just one for loop:

```php
$groups_name = 
['jhon' => 20,
'aliza' => 30,
'rehana' => 40,
'adiba' => 50,
'black' => 1000,
'white' => 7500,
'red' => 3500];

$inputs = [50, 70, 4500];

function get_names($array, $input){
    foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
        $target = abs($value - $input);
        if(in_array($target, array_values($array))){
            $pair = array_flip($array)[$target];
            echo "($name, $pair)";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Result:*

```php
get_names($groups_name, $inputs[0]); // (jhon, aliza)
get_names($groups_name, $inputs[1]); // (jhon, adiba)
get_names($groups_name, $inputs[2]); // (black, red)
```

Comment: He never responded to my original question on what he wants to happen in the case of multiple names summing to his value
Your 70 returns John and Aliza, but what about Aliza and rehana

Comment: yes yes brother in this  situation    print all names like  (jhon + aliza) and (Aliza + Rehana)

Comment: BROTHER   need some update    in your given code   if in put value is equal 3 names    please make some change in it if input vale is 120 then
output **(( Adiba + Rehana + Aliza )) **        or       if input vale is 1120 then

output **( Adiba + Rehana + Aliza + Black )**        if input value not match in whole array values then output msg show  **((Not Fount))**    @TAHER El Mehdi

Comment: In case of multiple names not two you could add an else if statement or another loop or use recerusion I don't how to deal with recursion but I just deal with case of two name as you provide in question's output?

Comment: ok brother thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Please make it minor update:

```php
$groups_name = 
['jhon' => 20,
'aliza' => 30,
'rehana' => 40,
'adiba' => 50,
'black' => 1000,
'white' => 7500,
'red' => 3500];

$inputs = [50, 70, 4500];

function get_names($array, $input){
    foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
        $target = abs($value - $input);
        if(in_array($target, array_values($array))){
            $pair = array_flip($array)[$target];
            echo "($name, $pair)";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Result:*

```php
get_names($groups_name, $inputs[0]); // (jhon, aliza)
get_names($groups_name, $inputs[1]); // (jhon, adiba)
get_names($groups_name, $inputs[2]); // (black, red)
```

- work only for two values
- please make some change in it   if input vale is 120  then

```
output ( Adiba + Rehana + Aliza )
```

if input vale is 1120  then

```
output ( Adiba + Rehana + Aliza + Black )
```

- if input value is not match in given array
- **then show msg not fount**

Comment: @TAHER El Mehdi